# I am making a very basic rock paper scissors game and it has to be in functions, but there is some problems

Tags: python

```
import random
import time

def intro():
  name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  print(f" Hello, {name} today we are going to be playing Rock, Paper, Scissors.")


def game():
  options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  print("What do you want: rock, paper, scissors?")
  answer = input()
  while answer not in options:
    print("Invalid choice. Please pick another option,")
    answer = input()

def process():
  bot = random.choice(options)
  print("Bot:"+ bot)
  print("User:" + answer)


def winner():
if bot == answer:
  print("Tie")
elif answer == "rock":
  if bot == "paper":
    print("Paper covers rock so computer wins")
  else: 
    print("Rock smashes scissors, so you win.")
elif answer == "paper":
  if bot == "rock":
    print("Paper covers rock user wins")
  else: 
    print("Scissorsr cuts paper so bot wins")
else: 
  if bot == "paper":
    print("scissors cuts paper so user wins")
  else:
    print("rock smashes scissors so bot wins") 



intro()
game()
process()
winner()
```

I am making a very basic rock paper scissors game and it has to be in functions, but there are some problems it keeps on having indentation problems and stuff. I need help fixing the code. Can someone take this code and run it on repl.it and then help me fix it out, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of global variables.

```
import random
import time

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
answer = ""
bot = ""
def intro():
  name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  print(f" Hello, {name} today we are going to be playing Rock, Paper, Scissors.")


def game():
  print("What do you want: rock, paper, scissors?")
  global answer
  answer = input()
  while answer not in options:
    print("Invalid choice. Please pick another option,")
    answer = input()

def process():
    global answer, bot
    bot = random.choice(options)
    print("Bot:"+ bot)
    print("User:" + answer)


def winner():
    if bot == answer:
      print("Tie")
    elif answer == "rock":
      if bot == "paper":
        print("Paper covers rock so computer wins")
      else: 
        print("Rock smashes scissors, so you win.")
    elif answer == "paper":
      if bot == "rock":
        print("Paper covers rock user wins")
      else: 
        print("Scissorsr cuts paper so bot wins")
    else: 
      if bot == "paper":
        print("scissors cuts paper so user wins")
      else:
        print("rock smashes scissors so bot wins") 



intro()
game()
process()
winner()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the variables as an argument to the functions:

```
import random
import time

def intro():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    print(f" Hello, {name} today we are going to be playing Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
def game():
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    print("What do you want: rock, paper, scissors?")
    answer = input()
    while answer not in options:
        print("Invalid choice. Please pick another option,")
        answer = input()
    return options,answer

def process(options,answer):
    bot = random.choice(options)
    print("Bot:"+ bot)
    print("User:" + answer)
    return bot
def winner(answer,bot):
    if bot == answer:
        print("Tie")
    elif answer == "rock":
        if bot == "paper":
            print("Paper covers rock so computer wins")
        else: 
            print("Rock smashes scissors, so you win.")
    elif answer == "paper":
        if bot == "rock":
            print("Paper covers rock user wins")
        else: 
            print("Scissorsr cuts paper so bot wins")
    else: 
        if bot == "paper":
            print("scissors cuts paper so user wins")
        else:
            print("rock smashes scissors so bot wins")
intro()
a,b=game()
c=process(a,b)
winner(b,c)
```

An example with `global` (though not recommended):

```
import random
import time

def intro():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    print(f" Hello, {name} today we are going to be playing Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
def game():
    global options
    global answer
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    print("What do you want: rock, paper, scissors?")
    answer = input()
    while answer not in options:
        print("Invalid choice. Please pick another option,")
        answer = input()
    

def process():
    global bot
    bot = random.choice(options)
    print("Bot:"+ bot)
    print("User:" + answer)
    
def winner():
    if bot == answer:
        print("Tie")
    elif answer == "rock":
        if bot == "paper":
            print("Paper covers rock so computer wins")
        else: 
            print("Rock smashes scissors, so you win.")
    elif answer == "paper":
        if bot == "rock":
            print("Paper covers rock user wins")
        else: 
            print("Scissorsr cuts paper so bot wins")
    else: 
        if bot == "paper":
            print("scissors cuts paper so user wins")
        else:
            print("rock smashes scissors so bot wins")
intro()
game()
process()
winner()
```

Comment: Ok thank you. But is there a way to do it without adding the return function and the other additional stuff.

Comment: Then, either a class or using ```global``` @Manavrana

Comment: Could you show me an example of my code with global please?

Comment: @Manavrana, check the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

A function should serve a purpose and return a value, especially since you need past values in your future functions.

```
import random
import time

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

def intro():
  name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  return name


def game():
  print("What do you want: rock, paper, scissors?")
  answer = input()
  while answer not in options:
    print("Invalid choice. Please pick another option,")
    answer = input()
  return answer

def process():
  bot = random.choice(options)
  return bot


def winner(bot, answer):
    if bot == answer:
      return "Tie"
    elif answer == "rock":
      if bot == "paper":
        return "Paper covers rock so computer wins"
      else:
        return "Rock smashes scissors, so you win."
    elif answer == "paper":
      if bot == "rock":
        return "Paper covers rock user wins"
      else:
        return "Scissorsr cuts paper so bot wins"
    else:
      if bot == "paper":
        return "scissors cuts paper so user wins"
      else:
        return "rock smashes scissors so bot wins"



name = intro()
print( f" Hello, {name} today we are going to be playing Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
answer = game()
bot = process()
print("Bot:", bot)
print("User:" , answer)
print( winner( bot, answer ) )
```